# WPF - Restrict dragging/dropping controls into another control at Design-Time

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to customize a wpf custom control, so it should restrict dropping (-drag and drop-) other controls into itself?

Let's say i am designing a specific control, witch (-by design-) may only contain some other user-defined controls, so i want deny the WPF-Designer from dropping any other control-type, is it passable at all?

I had google'd allot but did'nt find even one such a question.

Comment: You could create your own custom content control (derived from `Control`) where the property receiving the content is of a type that accepts only a certain type. All the eligible user-controls should have that type as a common base class. Of course your custom content control needs to do the necessary plumbing as the standard ContentControl would do. You can take inspiration from the [reference source for ContentControl](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentControl.cs,f8ee23c685054e71)...

Comment: @elgonzo, actually thats what i am asking, witch "Property" of a custom control (derived from `Control`) should be responsible for accepting child controls, on such a way so the WPF designer will be aware of it, and dictate the designer to act against it and restrict dropping different types.

Comment: @elgonzo can you show me some sample code, have you ever done such a thing in the past?